# Discord Python - OpenWeatherAPI Parse Weather Data

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I was making a Weather command for my bot, and i can't parse the weather part using requests, (Yes, i did .json() it), The code:

```
import requests
import discord
import random

from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands

colour = random.randint(0x000000, 0xffffff)

class Weather(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def weather(self, ctx, *, location: str=None):
        if location:
            result = requests.get(f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={location}&APPID=APP ID").json()
            embed = (discord.Embed(title=f"{location} Weather",
                                    description=result,
                                    colour=colour))
            location = result["name"]
            temp = result["main"]["temp"]
            wind_speed = result["wind"]["speed"]
            visibility = result["visibility"]
            weather = result["weather"]["main"]
            description = result["weather"]["description"]
            feels_like = result["main"]["feels_like"]

            await ctx.send(f"{location}\n{temp}\n{wind_speed}\n{visibility}\n{weather}\n{description}\n{feels_like}\n")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Please provide me with a location.")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Weather(client))
```

When i tried parsing the weather, it raised an error.

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

and i don't know why. But when i tried to format it, there was a "[]" at the weather part[image]

and i don't know how to parse with it.

Comment: Add [0] as the first index. You could make it into not a 2d array.

Comment: @arundeepchohan in the location?

Comment: result["weather"][0]["main"] something like this.

Comment: Np just upvote the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awnsered By [@arundeepchohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9901261/arundeep-chohan).
I Just need to make it to be indexed (add [0] before the second one)
Thank you again [@arundeepchohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9901261/arundeep-chohan)